# Python to C# Conversion of RGBA values not working

Tags: c#, python, rgba

I'm currently converting some python code to C#, and I'm having an issue with the RGBA C# libraries

```
# Original Python Code:
    d = math.sqrt( (x - size/2.0)**2 + (y - size/2.0)**2 )
    rgbVal = int(200*d/md + 50)
    rgba = (0,0,0, 255 - rgbVal)
    img.putpixel((x,y), rgba)

// My C# Code
double d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((x - DotSize / 2.0), 2) + Math.Pow((y - DotSize / 2.0), 2));
int rgbVal = (int) (200 * d / md + 50);
Color color = Color.FromArgb(255 - rgbVal, 0, 0, 0);     // ** ERROR **
img.SetPixel(x,y, color);
```

At both instances of the code d is equal to 106 and md is equal to 53. However the resulting rgbVal value is 450. 
This would obviously mean that 255 - 450 is -195, which causes an error to be thrown as each individual value must be between 0 and 255. 
Anyone have any idea how I can fix this. Please note that the data is the same when running both the python and C# versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize the value with mod.

```
// I'm a little confused by your code, so it's this
Color color = Color.FromArgb(255 - ((-190 + 255) % 255), 0, 0, 0);
// or this...
Color color = Color.FromArgb(((-190 + 255) % 255), 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: But the point is that the last line of the python code for the first iteration (bot sets of code are in a loop) would be img.SetPixel(0, 0, (0, 0, 0, -195)), which would be the same as the C# one. But I don't get why python is not complaining and C# is?

Comment: I think I might have solved my own problem. Rather than passing in the individual values, I shifted the values to a 32-bit color value.